# Why is ForkJoinPool not running all tasks?

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm trying to understand ForkJoinPools, so I made the following simple test class. Unfortunately it doesn't do what I'm expecting. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class UtilsShowcase {

    public static void main(String[] args){
            final UtilsShowcase us = new UtilsShowcase();
            us.run();
    }

    public void run(){
            forkJoinPoolDemo();
    }

    public void forkJoinPoolDemo(){
            final ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool();

            Future<String> result = forkJoinPool.submit(new MyTask(8));
            try {
                    result.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }       
   private class MyTask extends RecursiveTask<String> {
            final long num;

            MyTask(long number){
                    this.num = number;
            }

            protected String compute(){
                    System.out.println("In compute with number of "+num);
                    if (num > 1){
                            System.out.println("Generating two more tasks with number of "+num/2);

                            (new MyTask(num/2)).fork();
                            (new MyTask(num/2)).fork();

                    }
                    return "Returning from a number "+num;
            }
    }
}
```

I was expecting it to start off with the number 8, and then kick off two tasks for number 4, 4 tasks for number 2 and 8 tasks for number 1. Instead it prints out this:

```
In compute with number of 8
Generating two more tasks with number of 4
In compute with number of 4
Generating two more tasks with number of 2
In compute with number of 4
Generating two more tasks with number of 2
In compute with number of 2
Generating two more tasks with number of 1
In compute with number of 2
Generating two more tasks with number of 1
In compute with number of 1
In compute with number of 2
In compute with number of 1
```

It sort of gets part of it right - it prints out 2 number 4 tasks, but only 3 number 2s (instead of 4) and 2 numbers 1s (instead of 8!)

Many thanks!

Comment: The subtasks get forked, but never joined...

Comment: using the join result is much more fun http://ideone.com/BIjFjQ

Comment: Thanks! Yep, was just trying to get my head round the fork bit first. Now looking at the join part too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, answering my own question here.

Realized that the main thread was probably exiting before the other threads got to do all their work, and since ForkJoinPool is a daemon, it just silently ended. If I add

```
            try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

at the end of method forkJoinPoolDemo, I get the result I was expecting:

```
In compute with number of 8
Generating two more tasks with number of 4
In compute with number of 4
Generating two more tasks with number of 2
In compute with number of 2
Generating two more tasks with number of 1
In compute with number of 4
In compute with number of 1
Generating two more tasks with number of 2
In compute with number of 2
Generating two more tasks with number of 1
In compute with number of 2
Generating two more tasks with number of 1
In compute with number of 1
In compute with number of 1
In compute with number of 1
In compute with number of 1
In compute with number of 1
In compute with number of 2
Generating two more tasks with number of 1
In compute with number of 1
In compute with number of 1
```

Sanity restored :-)